# Call API Gateway REST API using Cognito Federated Identities

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have authenticated with Facebook and have the following:

- accessKeyId
- secretAccessKey
- identityId
- sessionToken

How can I call my api in API Gateway (without generating an sdk)?

Comment: Was there any updates on this ?

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out eventually. Not quite sure what the original problem was. Are you also seeking a solution or just wondering if this should be closed? Maybe share a link to your own question and I might be able to help. I was using JavaScript and the serverless framework and faced issues with configuring aws and also CORS. I can look at my cloudformation template if it's useful?

Comment: I am seeking a solutions so if you can guide me

Comment: Would also be interested in a solution to this.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I've authenticated with Facebook and received the accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, identityId, and sessionToken. I tried to use those to call my API Gateway, but none worked. What token did you use to call your API Gateway?

I'm able to call my API Gateway successfully with a user from the User Pool, but get the Unauthorized message when I try to call it with the authenticated Facebook user.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I found an answer for it using Postman.

This is the essence of it from [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html):

> 1. Launch Postman.
> 2. Enter the endpoint URL of a request in the address bar and choose the appropriate HTTP method from the drop-down list to the left of the
>      address bar.
> 3. If required, choose the **Authorization** tab. Choose **AWS Signature** for the authorization **Type**. Enter your AWS IAM user's access key ID in
>      the **AccessKey** input field. Enter your IAM user secret key in
>      **SecretKey**. Specify an appropriate AWS region that matches the region
>      specified in the invocation URL. Enter `execute-api` in **Service Name**.

This will work to successfully call a API Gateway. Only if a User Pool and Identity Pool have been correctly set-up, and the `Authorization` attribute in the `Method Request` setting for the API Gateway resource is set to `AWS_IAM`.

For more information about the AWS Signature for api calls check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156521/how-to-integrate-api-gateway-with-cognito-federated-identity-and-cognito-user-po). While this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919965/how-setup-header-in-postman-for-api-gateway-authenticated-with-cognito?rq=1) contains some more information, with pictures, about how to make a API Gateway request in Postman.