# How to test calls to an Amazon API gateway using Cognito Auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, curl, postman, amazon-cognito

I've got some lambdas behind Amazon's API Gateway, which is configured to restrict access to Cognito authenticated users. All works fine for users coming via a UI.

I'd like to test those APIs separately to the UI, using Postman ideally or failing that perhaps curl.

How can I send a Cognito-authenticated request via Postman, curl or similar, to the API Gateway?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How setup header in Postman for Api Gateway authenticated with Cognito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919965/how-setup-header-in-postman-for-api-gateway-authenticated-with-cognito)

Answer (score 1):

Try using Insomnia as a Rest client: https://insomnia.rest/

I see it has a tab for AWS auth settings.

[image]

Comment: Also remember to set CORS, and you can really just use any HTTP client and just add your jwt to the auth header.  Authorization: authResponse.getIdToken().getJwtToken()

Answer (score 0):

just have a look at the following post, i think it'd be helpful for you.

[How setup header in Postman for Api Gateway authenticated with Cognito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919965/how-setup-header-in-postman-for-api-gateway-authenticated-with-cognito)

Comment: I'm not using a federated identity provider, I'm using Cognito username and password auth.

Comment: if you are using cognito user pool, get the authentication token from cognito and provide in Authorization : Bearer <Bas64 Tocken -- which would be returned on authentication>. you can get the tocken from your frontend.